# Downloaded asset is not being loaded from local storage in android, using unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to load an object at run time from downloaded assetbundle in android local storage but no result is found. Though the assetbundle exists in local storage of my android device.

Please somebody help me to do so, following is the code which I have written:

```
public GameObject obj;

IEnumerable LoadObject()
{
    AssetBundle bundle = AssetBundle.CreateFromFile(Application.persistentDataPath + "/androidassetbundle4");
    yield return bundle;

    AssetBundleRequest request = bundle.LoadAssetAsync("boat", typeof(GameObject));
    yield return request;

    obj = request.asset as GameObject;
    obj.transform.position = new Vector3(0.08f, -2.345f, 297.54f);
    obj.transform.Rotate(350.41f,400f,20f);
    obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.0518f, 0.998f, 1.1793f);

    Instantiate(obj);

    bundle.Unload(false);

}//end of Method LoadObject
```

Answer (score 0):

`CreateFromFile` is deprecated. `LoadFromFile` and `LoadFromFileAsync` are the new functions to use. Not sure if that is the problem but the code below should do it.

```
IEnumerator LoadObject()
{
    AssetBundleCreateRequest bundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "assetbundlename"));
    yield return bundle;

    AssetBundle myLoadedAssetBundle = bundle.assetBundle;
    if (myLoadedAssetBundle == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Failed to load AssetBundle!");
        yield break;
    }

    AssetBundleRequest request = myLoadedAssetBundle.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>("boat");
    yield return request;

    obj = request.asset as GameObject;
    obj.transform.position = new Vector3(0.08f, -2.345f, 297.54f);
    obj.transform.Rotate(350.41f, 400f, 20f);
    obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.0518f, 0.998f, 1.1793f);

    Instantiate(obj);

    myLoadedAssetBundle.Unload(false);
}
```

Comment: 'UnityEngine.AssetBundle' does not contain definition for 'LoadFromFileAsync'.
I have been getting this error.

Comment: You must have Unity 5.3 and above.

Comment: @user3599561 So what happened? Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score -1):

you can't access file in local storage via CreateFromFile or LoadFromFile in android,instead use LoadFromCacheOrDownload and in android this is the address of your StreamingAssets : `"jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/"` 
as mentioned in unity docs : [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html)